# Google Cardboard : GL.LINES is drawing off limits for each eye

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm a user of Google Cardboard + Unity and I would like to draw custom 3D lines. For that I put a script on each eye camera that look like that :

```
void OnPostRender() 
{
    GL.InvalidateState();
    GL.PushMatrix();

    mat.SetPass(0);

    GL.Begin( GL.LINES );

    GL.Vertex(...);
    GL.Vertex(...);
    ...

    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();
}
```

While it's working great on computer (even on Oculus), it behaves differently on Android : lines are drawing off limits of the viewport which is annoying because the last viewport drawn pollutes the first one.

I can't post images but right eye lines overtake on left eye.
I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 + OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.0 is not available for that device).
Is there a way to avoid that behavior on Android ?

NB : GL.InvalidateState() is used to have the right colors, otherwise lines are black on android

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on your problem:

When I have to draw lines in the world, I like to use Vectrosity:

http://www.starscenesoftware.com/vectrosity.html
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/82

You set up the lines and they are persistent (but editable).  Since they exist in the world, they'll render in stereo just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
However I would like to find a way to do it with GL as I don't want to pay for a plugin that I'll use only for debug.